# How to combine three large text files in SQL to prepare for export to SPSS and R

Tags: sql, r, spss, large-files, flat-file

I have very limited experience with SQL or R, but I have received a very important dataset that was originally created in a SQL Database. It was exported into three separate text files, one of which is too large to open in Notepad. (3.92 GB) I need to be able to combine these three files together in SQL as they originally were, and export them into SPSS and R file formats. (I do have SQL Server Management Studio 17 on my computer, and again, I do have some experience, but it is very very limited.) I have tried asking the providers for guidance, and they have not been forthcoming. Any help would be greatly appreciated.[tblSurveyValueLabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37sa7.png) [tblSurveyVariableLabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du79g.png)[tblSurveyAnswer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFzwx.png)

Code so far:

```r
library(dbplyr)
library(haven)
library(RMariaDB)
library(RPostgres)
library(RSQLite)
library(odbc)
library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "servername",
                 Database = "dbname",
                 UID = "sa",
                 PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
                 Port = 1433
)

sa_db <- tbl(con, "tblSurveyAnswer")
sa_db

val_db <- tbl(con, "tblSurveyValueLabel")
# val_db

var_db <- tbl(con, "tblSurveyVariableLabel")
# var_db

saval_db <- merge(sa_db, val_db, by = c("Survey","Question"), all = TRUE)
saval_db_order <- saval_db[order(saval_db$Survey, saval_db$Question), ] # Sorting data by Survey/Question
str(saval_db)

savalvar_db <- merge(saval_db, var_db, by = c("Survey", "Question"), all = TRUE)
str(savalvar_db)

write_sav(savalvar_db, "savalvar_db.sav")
```

Comment: Pictures of each of the files are attached as links above.

Comment: Do you have to do it in SQL? you can do this in R and use `dbplyr` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/dbplyr.html to combine and write out files to SPSS using `haven` https://haven.tidyverse.org/. You can save the data.frame to a txt (csv) or an rds file for importing into R later

Comment: This sounds like something that would be worth looking into, but I have very limited experience in R as well. I will look into trying this, and see how far I can get.

Comment: Well here to help. Try something first and post here on what you tried and where you got stuck. Briefly, connect to do server. find a common key between them to join the data,  write the query and fetch the results and write/export results

Comment: So, my code so far in R:
library(dbplyr)
library(haven)
library(RMariaDB)
library(RPostgres)
library(RSQLite)
library(odbc)
library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "servername",
                 Database = "dbname",
                 UID = "sa",
                 PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword ("Database password"),
                 Port = 1433)

sa_db<-tbl(con, "tblSurveyAnswer")
sa_db

Comment: Got stuck on this last bit, as it seems that there is an issue with accessing variables in SQL that are set to varchar(MAX) which at least a couple of mine were. Working on troubleshooting this.

Comment: Great progress . Could you update your question with the code. So we can take a closer look..

Comment: Well, I successfully wrote what I hope is all of the data to an SPSS file. I won't be able to check it until I have access to SPSS tomorrow, but I'll update this once I do! Thanks very much for the help so far.